# Lightning Design using slds-text-align_center does not allow me to adjust width

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

I have a nested component and when the parent displays it on a full width page the child expands the entire screen and does not look good. I used "slds-text-align_center" to center it, but then tried to add style in the div to adjust width to 700px. This does not seem to work. If I do the style by itself then the width works, BUT my component is then left justified. Any ideas to center AND get width to 700px?

```
<div class="slds-text-align_center" >
    <c:AddressVerify/>
</div>
```

Thanks!
Ryan

Comment: would you like to open the child component in a popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to position `c:AddressVerify` in the middle of your parent component with white space on the sides? If so, something like this could help.

```
<lightning:layout multipleRows="false">
    <lightning:layoutItem size="12" smallDeviceSize="1" mediumDeviceSize="3" largeDeviceSize="3" padding="around-small"/>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="12" smallDeviceSize="10" mediumDeviceSize="6" largeDeviceSize="6" padding="around-small">
        <c:AddressVerify/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="12" smallDeviceSize="1" mediumDeviceSize="3" largeDeviceSize="3" padding="around-small"/>
</lightning:layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another wrapper element. If your component is meant to have other alignments within itself, you'll need to further add an additional alignment back to the left:

```
<div class="slds-text-align_center">
    <div class="container slds-text-align_left">
        <c:AddressVerify/>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.THIS .container {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 700px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

---

In general, though, you should consider using lightning:layout to make responsive designs in your components, but if you're absolutely certain you want to use pixel measurements, this is one way you could do that.

---

Alternatively, `slds-align_absolute-center` may also serve your purpose:

```
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
    <div class="container">
        <c:AddressVerify/>
    </div>
</div>
```